# Sending keys correctly after text replace in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to do something very basic.

I want when I type `clog` for autoHotKey to replace it with `console.log();`

Which I got working using this command:

```
::clog::console.log()`;
```

However, it adds a blank space character after it and leaves the caret there.  I'm trying to remove that extra white space and put the caret inside the parenthesis automatically, but if do this, nothing changes:

```
::clog::console.log()`;
SendInput, {Left}
Return
```

I also tried this and a few other variants with no luck.

```
::clog::console.log()`;
SendInput, {Backspace}, {Left}, {Left}
Return
```

Seems it should be very simple, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

So turns out the solution was to just put the commands on the next line:

```
::clog::
Send console.log(){;}{Left}{Left}
Return
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out!